# How to go about having PHP validation fall backs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, validation

just wondering what the best way to go about having both javascript and PHP validation.

So, currently I have js validation for just an empty field and that then send the data to the PHP page.

What can I do for e.g.

```
if ($_POST['username'] == '') {
   die();
}
```

I want to have PHP validation for more security and also for people with js turned off.

I could set a session on fail, and then check next to the field if there is a session set and then on true echo out a empty field message?

But then how do I stop that working when js is enabled etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If js is enabled, before the form submits, it can set the value of a hidden form input. PHP checks for the value and behaves one way if it's set, another if it's not.

Comment: You *always* need to do application level validation regardless of how much pre-validating you do with JavaScript. If you're using a [framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/), use their built-in validation methods. You cannot trust the client to properly validate anything, ever. Maybe they have JavaScript turned off, or maybe they're trying to hack around and submit something they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need serverside validation also... I do it (most of the time) like so...

```
$errors= array();
$username=$_POST['username'];

if ($username == '') {
   $errors[]='username can not be empty!' ;
}
```

after all the validation stuff (you can and have to do more validation) you could check if there are errors set...

```
if (empty($errors)) {
//your code when there are no errors
}
```

if there are errors you could echo  them to the user.

```
    if (!empty($errors)) {
      foreach($errors as $err){
         echo $err;
       }
    }
```

also don't forget to mysql_real_escape_string() your posted data if you plan to save it in a database.

Comment: If i have the code for the database query on a seperate page to the form.

How do i go about echoing out errors on the page with the form.

I can redirect back to the original page the user came from but how do the error messages get stored